# How to reach breakpoint in C++ destructor in CLion?

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints, clion

I set a breakpoint in a destructor, which only gets called, when the program finishes completely. Now I start the program with CLion's debugger, but it never reaches the destructor. When I press on finish in CLion the debugger closes and the breakpoint never gets reached. How can I reach the breakpoint in the destructor in CLion?

Comment: Without knowing the relevant code it is not really possible to tell. Do other breakpoints work? If yes you probably have optimizations turned on and the compiler is might optimize everything in the destructor away, or at least that much that the breakpoint does not work.

Comment: Other breakpoints work, but the only way to reach the breakpoint in the destructor is to close the debugger in clion, which ofc well closes the debugger.

Comment: You need to finish the program and not the debugger to reach the breakpoint in the destructor.

Comment: I know, the question is how?

Comment: @Hakaishin, depends very much on your program. Is it possible to make it quit when hitting a key?

Comment: Usually I press ctrl + c, but this does not work in the clion environment

Comment: Can you send a signal to it with `kill <pid>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to stop looping in your main thread, and jump to `return 0;` at the end of your `int main(...) {`. Alternatively, you can use `exit(0)`, I believe. (Source: [Difference between "return 0" and "exit (0)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383015/difference-between-return-0-and-exit-0))

There's more:

You need to share your code, but there's this information, which you may find useful:

Please see these references:

> [Are Basic Object Destructors Called On Exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314143/are-basic-object-destructors-called-on-exit)
>
> Note that objects with automatic storage are not destroyed by calling exit (C++).
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/

The problem could be that, during exit, your destructor is never called, anyway. Hence, it is a leak but the OS will handle it.